Google Sheets DATEVALUE formula is returning the wrong data
I'm trying to reference a cell and return the date using index-match.  For dates with number formats set as "Mmm YY", the formula returns the referenced month, the year as the day, and the current year instead of the input (i.e. input 2/28/2023, formatted as Feb 23, datevalue returns 2/23/2024).
I found the date only parses properly when number format is set as mm/dd/yyyy.  Year, month, and day formulas return the proper values (unable to include a snip due to VPN restrictions).
Example:
Cell A1 contains the date input as 2/28/2023 formatted as "Mmm YYYY" date format.  2/28/2023 translates to 44985 unformatted.
Cell B1 contains =datevalue(A1) and returns 2/23/2024.

Can you enter the problem you encountered in a sample file using the link https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform

Converting the Absolute Value TO_DATE
You were right about your theory, it is due to parsing issue. I created a workaround for you. I have converted your data back to absolute value and changed back to date. Using 2 Formula to go around the parsing issues.
Try this:
=TO_DATE(ABS(A1))

Sample Output:

In cell A, I formatted the date as Mmm YY. Then, in cell B, I used a formula to convert it back to the actual date in MM-DD-YY.
Reference:

ABS

TO_DATE



I am afraid that this is misleading. The abs() function does nothing to change the underlying dateserial value, unless it is before the Sheets epoch (31 December 1899). The to_date() function does not change the underlying dateserial either. It just formats a dateserial as a date, hiding the time portion, if any. The formula given in the answer will just show the date in A1 in a different format, and will not address the issue the OP describes. See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.

@doubleunary, it looks correct to me. I think that the OP is having issues using the data, for an index- match. I think the formula provided is correct to fix the issue. However, on your answer which I tested it seems that date values provided are still being parsed incorrectly despite following the instruction. By the way I also tested it on both OP's possible custom string format and your format. It does seem like it does the trick for the data to be usable on Index - Match string.

There might be some disconnect between how my answers are being perceived feel free to highlight so I can do an edit. I wanna reiterate that it doesn't fix the parsing issue, but rather corrects the format issue that can be used for the index - match the op is originally looking forward to do.

When a date is fed to index() or match(), these functions use the underlying dateserial rather than the formatted datetime shown in the cell. abs() and to_date() cannot help with that, since they do not modify the underlying dateserial (unless it is before the epoch, which does not seem to be the case here.)

So I've tested using to_date(abs(index(ref,match(),match()))) and it worked to pull the proper date where datevalue(...) failed, so this was a useful workaround.  I'll read the reference in the first comment to see if I can understand better why datevalue failed in the first place.  You guys have been awesome.  Thanks a million!
